# Android - как считать и вывести на экран обложку трека?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Доброй ночи! Есть задача - mp3 файл с вшитой в него обложкой альбома проигрывается в плеере, и эту обложку нужно считать и вывести на экран. Выводить картинку можно любым способом - хоть с помощью ImageView, хоть с помощью Canvas. На плюсы не скуплюсь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для API >= 10 :

```
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();     
        retriever.setDataSource("/.../Track.mp3");     
        byte[] data = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();     
        retriever.release();     
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!
Как раз то, что я искал.

Answer (score 0):

О [тегах](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_(%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) уже читали? А дальше любую подходящую библиотеку, например, [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic)

Comment: Не, я пока что не могу подключать библиотеки. Помню, что здесь очень давно видел такой же вопрос, там человеку помогли способом с Bitmap.decodeResource(...)